# Copy constructor for connect4 malloc errors

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I'm trying to write a minimax algorithm to solve connect 4 with alpha-beta pruning.  I can't get to any of that because I cant copy the game board...

default constructor:

```
gameStatus::gameStatus(){
 13     gameData = new long[42];
 14     gameBoard[0] = &(gameData[0]);
 15     gameBoard[1] = &(gameData[7]);
 16     gameBoard[2] = &(gameData[14]);
 17     gameBoard[3] = &(gameData[21]);
 18     gameBoard[4] = &(gameData[28]);
 19     gameBoard[5] = &(gameData[35]);
 20     
 21     int i;
 22     for (i = 0; i < 42; i++)
 23     {
 24       gameData[i] = 0;
 25     }
 26     
 27     currentTurn = 1;
 28     player1Score = 0;
 29     player2Score = 0;
 30     pieceCount = 0;
 31     gameFile = 0;
 32     utilityValue = 0;
 33   }
```

My copy constructor is as follows: (I've tried using 'this->' before every one of them, also tried combining lines 21/22 into just gameData = g.gameData)

```
 21   gameStatus(const gameStatus &g){
 22     gameData = new long[42];
 23     gameData = g.gameData;
 24     gameBoard[0] = &(g.gameData[0]);
 25     gameBoard[1] = &(g.gameData[7]);
 26     gameBoard[2] = &(g.gameData[14]);
 27     gameBoard[3] = &(g.gameData[21]);
 28     gameBoard[4] = &(g.gameData[28]);
 29     gameBoard[5] = &(g.gameData[35]);
 30     currentTurn = g.currentTurn;
 31     player1Score = g.player1Score;
 32     player2Score = g.player2Score;
 33     pieceCount = g.pieceCount;
 34     gameFile = g.gameFile;
 35     utilityValue = g.utilityValue;
 36     }
```

No matter what I try, if I include this call in the aiPlay function:

```
429     gameStatus tmpGame(currentGame);
```

here's what happens. my move:

```
MaxConnect-4 game
Current Board:
 -----------------
 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 
 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 
 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 
 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 
 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 
 | 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 | 
 -----------------
```

CPU move:

```
MaxConnect-4 game
Current Board:
 -----------------
 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 
 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 
 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 
 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 
 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 
 | 0 0 0 2 1 0 10414574138294272 | 
 -----------------
```

and then on the next CPU move i get this:

malloc: *** error for object 0x7fe521402b50: pointer being freed was not allocated

Comment: `gameData = new long[42];
 gameData = g.gameData;`  This is immediately a memory leak.

Comment: In your copy constructor, did you mean `gameData = new long[42];  memcpy(gameData, g.gameData, 42*sizeof(*gameData));`  what is `gameBoard`?  where is it defined?  You probably don't want to point gameBoard[i] to some location in the the "other" object `g`'s `gameData` array.

Comment: `gameData = new long[42];  gameData = g.gameData;` you are leaking right there

Comment: No.  You can do that.  You need to `memcpy` or see @alter answer below and use a for loop.

Comment: @MFisherKDX thank you!!! memcpy() did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a memory leak, and false sharing.

```
gameStatus(const gameStatus &g){
    gameData = new long[42];
    gameData = g.gameData;
```

Here, you ask for 42 `long`s, receive a pointer to the newly allocated data, and store it in `gameData`. This pointer, which you're responsible for `delete[]`ing, is *immediately* lost when you overwrite it with the address of `g`'s data, in the line `gameData = g.gameData`. Remember that copying a pointer is a shallow copy, not a deep copy. After a copy like `gameStatus g2 = g1;`, *both* games will point to the same `gameData`, causing double deletion and spooky bugs.

To fix this, remove the line `gameData = g.gameData;`, and instead iterate over the entries of `gameData`, assigning each `g.gameData[i]` to `gameData[i]`, which would be a deep copy.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 42; ++i){
        gameData[i] = g.gameData[i];
    }
```

---

```
    gameBoard[0] = &(g.gameData[0]);
    gameBoard[1] = &(g.gameData[7]);
    gameBoard[2] = &(g.gameData[14]);
    gameBoard[3] = &(g.gameData[21]);
    gameBoard[4] = &(g.gameData[28]);
    gameBoard[5] = &(g.gameData[35]);
```

Here, you set the entries of `gameBoard` (which I assume are used for convenient array indexing; I can't tell from what you've shown) to point to the *other* game's data, not to your own data. You probably want to point to your own data.

```
    gameBoard[0] = &(gameData[0]); // or equivalently, gameData
    gameBoard[1] = &(gameData[7]); // or equivalently, gameData + 7
    gameBoard[2] = &(gameData[14]);
    gameBoard[3] = &(gameData[21]);
    gameBoard[4] = &(gameData[28]);
    gameBoard[5] = &(gameData[35]);
```

---

```
    currentTurn = g.currentTurn;
    player1Score = g.player1Score;
    player2Score = g.player2Score;
    pieceCount = g.pieceCount;
    gameFile = g.gameFile;
    utilityValue = g.utilityValue;
}
```

The rest of the constructor looks fine at first glance, but I can't be sure. You would need to provide the definitions of all these class members to be certain. But assuming that none of these are raw pointers, this should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you implemented a destructor that deletes the array `gameData`.

You are stealing memory from what you copy. That might be fine for a move constructor, but it's not fine for a copy constructor.

```
gameStatus(const gameStatus &g) {
    gameData = new long[42]; // leaked memory

    // g.gameData will be destroyed
    // this->gameData will be equal to a deleted resource
    gameData = g.gameData;

    gameBoard[0] = &(g.gameData[0]);

    // ...
}
```

What you want is to copy the value:

```
gameStatus(const gameStatus &g) {
    gameData = new long[42]; // not leaked

    std::copy(g.gameData, g.gameData + 42, gameData);

    gameBoard[0] = &(gameData[0]);

    // ...
}
```

This will copy values one by one.